# Can't first initialise singleton and only than use it

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, grand-central-dispatch

I have a singletone initialisation class method:

```
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance
{
    static PanoramaDataManager *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[PanoramaDataManager alloc] init];
        [sharedInstance getTokenForPanoramaAPIAccess];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

- (void) getTokenForPanoramaAPIAccess
{
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"login" : kPanoramaAPILogin, @"password" : kPanoramaAPIPassword};
    PanoramaDataCommand *command = [[PanoramaDataCommand alloc] initWithUrl:[self urlToService:kPanoramaAPIGetToken withParams:params]
                                                                       data:nil
                                                                    caption:@"Получение токена для доступа к API панорам"];
    [command executeWithSuccess:^(PanoramaDataCommand *operation) {
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSDictionary *result = [command result];
            if (result)
                self.token = result[@"token"];
            NSLog(@"self.token = %@", self.token);
        });
    }
                   errorHandler:^(NSError *error) {
                       dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                           [BxAlertView showError:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Ошибка при получении токена: %@", error.description]];
                       });
                   }
                  cancelHandler:^{

                  }];
}
```

So I try to make a GET request to get token for the other requests, but now there is a problem - after the initialisation of the singleton some times later when all the rest requests are completed I only receive the message in log - that the token is received. I want to be sure that I get the token before return the shared instance. How could I do that? Is it a good approach? Thanks

Comment: finish your authentication before calling other services, store your token and login status in some centralized data manager, later when login is successful start calling other services whose data is required and finally show the view once you have everything

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong synchronization mechanism for the job. `dispatch_once` only makes sense for *synchronous* initialization. It's basically equivalent to this pseudocode (but much faster):

```
acquire global_mutex
if (!already_initialized)
    initialize()
    already_initialized = YES
release global_mutex
```

If that `initialize()` part kicks off an asynchronous job and then returns, the `already_initialized` flag gets set to YES—which is a lie, because you're not actually initialized until the asynchronous job finishes. So everyone else stomping around using uninitialized values.

The easiest way around this is to do the initialization before starting all of the other threads (or tasks in your thread pool) that need whatever you're initializing.

If that's not possible, then you need to move the `already_initialized = YES` equivalent to the end of the asynchronous initialization task. You can use a barrier, an atomic/interlocked/CAS integer, a condition variable, a lock around a boolean, whatever seems appropriate, but one thing you can't use is `dispatch_once`.